# How can I mount Android encrypted FS on desktop Linux?

Tags: linux, encryption, android

There is "vdc" command line utility in Android. Is there something similar for regular desktop Linux?

Reading of https://source.android.com/security/encryption/ didn't help.

Comment: Do you have a copy of the android drive/partition? Are you connecting to the android device through a data/usb cable while it's running?

Comment: I have a copy..

Comment: Ok, is it a LUKS device, like does `cryptsetup -v isLuks <device>` say anything interesting? Or can you already mount it and browse (encrypted) files?

Comment: No, it is not a luks device. It is specific Android implementation. Please read the link. I just wonder whether it is possible to mount this partition on desktop linux.

Comment: Well, the link says *"Android full disk encryption is based on dm-crypt"* and LUKS is a feature of dm-crypt... if it doesn't use LUKS then it likely uses plain dm-crypt, but it looks like it has it's own custom key storage & encryption. even has the "Android Open Source Project cryptfs.c file" available. But I don't know if anyone has gotten it to run on a regular linux, with the source code it should be possible...

Comment: http://forensicswiki.org/wiki/How_To_Decrypt_Android_Full_Disk_Encryption brute-force, but if you have the key, maybe useful

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/145443/how-to-decrypt-adopted-storage explains this. I'd mark as a duplicate, but it's on a different SE site.